# Waiting for a dependent request to complete within a Visual Studio Web test

Tags: visual-studio-2012, webrequest, web-testing

A request within my web test has multiple dependent requests:

```
REQUEST
 DEP REQUEST A
 DEP REQUEST B
```

I need for the request to B to wait until A has completed because I need to extract a value from the response of A and put it into the request for B.

Is this something that is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking the dependent request out and pasting it back as a separate request. 
When recording the scenario within Fiddler I could see the order of the requests and which were requests/dependent requests and so the Visual Studio web test recorder got this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might remove dependant request A from that top level request and add it as a totally new request. Dependant requests can be removed with a plugin. A web search for "WebTestDependentFilter" will find an example of the code, or see page 189 of the **Visual Studio Performance Testing Quick Reference Guide** on [Codeplex](http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com/).